# add_rewrite_rule not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have an url like that `http://localhost/leneufbreton/achat-immobilier-neuf/programme-neuf/?ville=brest` and I want to transformed to that `http://localhost/leneufbreton/achat-immobilier-neuf/programme-neuf/brest` or that `http://localhost/leneufbreton/achat-immobilier-neuf/programme-neuf-brest`

I was trying to use `add_rewrite_rule` but nothing happend.
This is my code action that I used:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
   add_rewrite_rule('^programme-neuf/([^/]*)/', 'programme-neuf/?ville=$matches[1]', 'top');

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Any idea please ?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the dollar sign with \

```
add_rewrite_rule('^programme-neuf/([^/]*)/', 'programme-neuf/?ville=\$matches[1]', 'top');
```